# File downloading stopped after about 1 minute in MVC action with File return Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, export-to-csv

I'm using `MVC 5.0` and I got an action to download data as a `CSV` file.
when the web site published, if the result file size is greater than `9 Mb`, the file downloading process will be stopped in the browser. and nothing happens.
There is no console or network error in the browser `inspect element` section.
there is no exception also.

Besides, in the `local system` this action work properly, I got another action to `export an excel file`, unfortunately, it has the same problem in the same scenario.
Is this error related to `IIS` or not?

I modified the 'maxRequestLength' in web.config and it set to `99999` but didn't work

Mvc action return part:

```
return File(fileByteArray, "application/csv", ReportFileName);
```

Js Methods:

```
 function DownloadCSV(formName, url) {
var formSelector = 'form[name=' + formName + ']';
var params = $(formSelector).serializeFormToUri();
window.location = url + params;
```

}

```
$.fn.serializeFormToUri = function () {

    var form = this;
    var data = serializeForm(form);

    var uri = '?';

    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        if(index !== 0)
            uri = uri + '&';
        uri = uri + item.name + '=' + item.value;
    });
    return uri;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After so many research, we found there are some restrictions in our **WAF (Web application firewall)** which does not allow to download a big file from the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running IIS7 or later, you might also have to increase the maxAllowedContentLength, which basically limits the size of responses sent to the client. It should go in your web.config file.

This is about 1GB:

```
    <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thank you guys.
I found the answer by my own.
The problem was related to server security limitation and WAF(Web Application Firewall) configurations.